# SQL Consecutive Pairs of a ROW excluding an odd count row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of data with two fields Id and FkId, the Id field will ALWAYS be numbered 1 to 100 and never anything else. The FkId is my important value.

I am looking for pairs where the important Value is the same for consecutive rows and must be in a set of 2. I am using version 8 of MySQL.

```
Id FkId
1   2
2   2
3   NULL
4   5
5   5
6   5
7   8
8   8 
9   NULL
10  NULL
11  7
12  NULL
```

- Rows 1 and 2 are pairs
- Rows 4 and 5 are pairs
- Rows 7 and 8 are pairs
- Rows 5 and 6 are NOT pairs because 5 is already paired with 4.

Notice Row 6 this would result in a bad value pair.
Any FkId that had a value and no consecutive matching FkId would also result in a bad value pair. 
Consecutive NULLs are excluded from the Value Pair test - they are to be disregarded unless the previous row had value and the next was null - in which case this would result in a bad value pair test.

What I am really looking to find out is if the data sets fail this test. 
So, for example, it can be a function that I call from a procedure, I just need to verify the data fits this pattern.

I have this query

```
SELECT  Distinct h1.Id, h1.FkId, h2.Id, h1.FkId
FROM ([WorkingTemp].[dbo].[MyData] h1
JOIN [WorkingTemp].[dbo].[MyData] h2 ON
  h1.Id +1 = h2.Id    )  
WHERE h1.FkId = h2.FkId 
GROUP BY h1.Id, h2.Id, h1.FkId, h2.FkId
```

Which has the problem that considering the sample table data below for rows 8, 9, and 10 is returned and considered to be pair set 8 & 9, 9 & 10.

Against this data set:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydata` (
  `Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FkId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

USE test;

INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (5, NULL);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (6, 3);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (7, NULL);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (8, 5);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (9, 5);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (10, 5);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (11, NULL);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (12, 7);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (13, NULL);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (14, 7);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (15, NULL);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (16, NULL);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (17, NULL);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (18, NULL);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (19, NULL);
INSERT INTO  `test`.`mydata` (`Id`,`FkId`) VALUES (20, NULL);
```

Comment: Is it SQLServer? If so why is tagged with `mysql`?

Comment: You didn't tell us what your desired result would look like.

Comment: @ken . . . Can the `fkid`s repeat for different pairs?

Comment: @peterm tagged MySQL for MySQL ..not tagged sql-server

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes different pairs are allowed to repeat - just I need that if Id is 1 then fkId for the next row after the fkId must match the fkId .

Comment: @P.Salmon from the write up:
What I am really looking to find out is if the data sets fail this test. So, for example, it can be a function that I call from a procedure, I just need to verify the data fits this pattern. Row and Row +1 the fkID must match , if not the whole thing is a fail.

Comment: I think you need something procedural to do this - a cursor may be the way to go.

Comment: @P.Salmon I ended up using a nested  loop. I liked the other possible solutions because they are cleaner than While, if then While if then .. but in the end after banging my head for too long, I used the loop iteration. The rows will never be more than 100 so speed is fine . I wrapped it in a function for that specific use case so I could simply call it RowFkIdMatch().

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about *consecutive* values, you can use `lead()` and `lag()`.  Then, you can approach this as a gaps-and-islands problem.  The ones that fail are:

```
select fkid
from (select md.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fkid order by id) as seqnum
      from mydata
     ) md
where fkid is not null
group by fkid, (id - seqnum)
having count(*) <> 2;
```

This returns all adjacent values that are not pairs.  It allows the values to repeat.

If `fkid`s cannot repeat, aggregation is sufficient:

```
select fkid
from mydata
where fkid is not null
group by fkid
having min(id) = max(id + 1)
```

Comment: I am not sure row-number() is available in MySQL

Comment: yes and FkIds can repeat , so for example row 11 can be a 5, in which case I have 2 pair sets , 8 & 9, and 10 & 111 which is an acceptable result . The lead and lag functions sounds interesting because I just want islands of 2 however in the case of 4 identical  I have no gap so I am not sure if that will work.  perhaps an iteration loop might be simplest for such a small data set - not sure how long it will take to increment row if next row is same fkID, then next row test.

Comment: *@ken . . . Instead of `having count(*) <> 2` you can just check for an even number:  `having mod(count(*), 2) = 0`.  And `row_number()` is available in MySQL 8+; as I write this comment, I don't see any version mentioned.